# "She" or "her" following "no one but"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, pronouns

Which pronoun is correct in the following sentence?

> No one but **her/she** ever made a perfect score on the test

The answer according to the book is *"her"*, but it is getting on my nerves.
I tried solving it by making a different statement as follows:

> She made a perfect score on the test

Why does using "No one but" change it to accusative case?

Comment: I'd say either "her" or "she" is acceptable here.  To me, "her" in this context sounds more modern, and more colloquial.  "She" sounds like something my grandfather would have said - it is nominative after all.  I would probably use either one of them, depending on how the mood grabbed me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*But* is here a preposition and when a pronoun follows a preposition it is in the accusative case. If you substitute *except* for *but*, which more or less has the same meaning, you will see that it has to be *her*.

Comment: wow using "except" for "but" really clears it.Thank You

Comment: I'm glad it helps.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Congrats on 40K!

Answer (score 6):

Traditionally, it should be *"no one but him"* if the phrase is an object phrase, and *"no one but he"* if it is a subject phrase. Consider the following passages from Shakespeare:

> It is, because no one should sway but he;
>   No one but he should be about the king;
>
> I'll fight with none but thee; 
>   for I do hate thee
>
> The quarrel toucheth none but us alone;
>
> Then yield, my lords; and here conclude with me
>   That Margaret shall be queen, and none but she.

You use the same preposition you would use if you removed *"none but"*—*he should sway; he should be about the king; I'll fight with thee; The quarrel toucheth us; she [Margaret] shall be queen.* This is explained quite cogently in [Lindley Murray's *English Grammar*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nobody+but+them%22&biw=1624&bih=672&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1750%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1850&tbm=bks#tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F1750%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F1850&tbm=bks&q=%22nobody+but+him%22) from 1808.

Today, some people still use this system, although it appears that the majority of people always use the accusative case, as explained in Barrie's answer.

[Garner's Modern American Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=FwmQpyibKkAC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=garner+%22no+one+but%22&source=bl&ots=4_g7zIOOf3&sig=f_LDwL6Ipn9RwHKm9VODgq7gTDc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyuaWGtoHLAhXFWCYKHbxBDl0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=garner%20%22no%20one%20but%22&f=false) recommends the nominative case when the *but* phrase precedes the verb, and the accusative when it follows. They give an example:

> None of the defendants but he were convicted.
>   None of the defendants were convicted but him.

From the [American Heritage Book of English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=BEHFyMCdwssC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%22Should+you+say+No+one+but+I+read+the+book+or+No+one+but+me+read+the+book?%22&source=bl&ots=yrmEdswIUu&sig=q2duLhjkAfaC9aDmSUMamKcadnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMhvT53YHLAhUFHD4KHZJRAQ0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Should%20you%20say%20No%20one%20but%20I%20read%20the%20book%20or%20No%20one%20but%20me%20read%20the%20book%3F%22&f=false):

> Should you say *No one but I read the book* or *No one but me read the book*? If *but* is a conjunction in these sentences, you should use the nominative form *I*. If *but* is a preposition, you should use *me*. ...
>   These recommendations [the accusative case] are supported by 73% of the Usage Panel when the *but* phrase precedes the verb and by 93% of the Usage Panel when the *but* phrase follows the verb.

So when *but* comes before the verb, it appears that around a quarter of the Usage Panel is still following the traditional system, which has been used since the time of Shakespeare.

Which one should you use on a standardized English test? They shouldn't put this kind of question on a standardized test, since it appears that grammar books differ in their recommendations. But it appears that [they do](http://gmatclub.com/forum/sc-barrons-no-one-but-him-15243.html). I don't know which grammar the testing agencies like.

Comment: I think the question is more related with how you define the word **but**. If you replace **but** with **excluding**, what case would you use? "No one excluding **she** ever made a perfect score" is not grammatical. Some dictionaries like Oxford Online Dictionary classifies **excluding** as a [preposition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/excluding).

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are correct. It largely depends on how you define the word [**but**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/but). If you define it as a **preposition**, you have to use the objective (accusative) case **her** as Barrie England mentioned in the answer.

> No one but **her** ever made a perfect score on the test.

In the above sentence, *but* could be replaced with *except (for)* or [*excluding*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/excluding).

However, if you define it as a **conjunction**, the subjective (nominative) case could also be used.

> No one but **she** ever made a perfect score on the test.

The above sentence is coordinated from the below sentence:

> No one has ever made a perfect score on the test, but **she** has made a
>   perfect score on the test.

in the same way as "He and she went to the same school" is coordinated from:

> He went to the same school and **she** went to the same school.

It is not disputable you have to use the **she** in the above sentence, however, the word **but** could be used both as a *conjunction* and *preposition* making its usage more complicated than *and*. One thing for sure is you can't use the subjective (nominative) case **she** after **except (for)** and **excluding**.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: Sometimes you have to use *she* after *except*; when it's a conjunction. Consider:  *"All of my friends went to the same school, except she didn't."*

Comment: @PeterShor Except can be used both as a preposition and a conjunction. Of course **she** would be used if except is used as a conjunction.